# Have output of 'sudo' script printed to same Powershell window?

Tags: windows, powershell, sudo

I found this 'sudo' script online:

```
function Elevate-Process
{
    $file, [string]$arguments = $args;
    if([System.IO.File]::Exists("$(get-location)\$file"))
    {
    $file = "$(Get-Location)\$file";
    }
    $psi = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo $file;
    $psi.Arguments = $arguments;
    $psi.Verb = "runas";
    [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi);
}

set-alias sudo Elevate-Process;
```

It works fine, but the problem is that if you use it with applications that don't have a GUI, it spawns the process in a different elevated window.

For example, if I run `sudo sfc /scannow`, the output will be in a new window, with the old window giving me the following output:

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
      0       2      280         76 ...55     0.00   7964 sfc
```

Would it be possible to have the output of the command ran with 'sudo' displayed within the non-elevated Powershell window? If not, is there a different way of elevating a non-Administrator Powershell window that does not print output to a separate window?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a way to redirect the output of another process to your seperate process, i.e. interprocess communication. The "sudo" Function you are using is just starting a process with the verb "runas", which prompts UAC before it starts a seperate process. There are several solutions listed here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

A workaround, which may be enough, is to redirect the stdout of your application to a text file, and read the output.

```
function Elevate-Process
{
param(
$file, 
[string]$arguments = $args,
[string]$RedirectStandardOutput = 'C:\redirected.txt'
)
if([System.IO.File]::Exists("$(get-location)\$file"))
{
$file = "$(Get-Location)\$file";
}
$psi = new-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo 'cmd.exe';
$psi.Arguments = "/c $file $arguments > $RedirectStandardOutput";
$psi.Verb = "runas";
$process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi);
get-content -path $RedirectStandardOutput -wait
}
set-alias sudo Elevate-Process;
```

run the application `sudo sfc /cannow -RedirectStandardOutput C:\Wherever\Whatever.txt`
when the command has finished processing you will have to select `ctrl + c` to get back to the prompt.

Otherwise, the simplest\reliable methods will be to pass the output via Named Pipes, or through TCP\IP Sockets.